# how to associate an application with Parse?

Tags: github, parse-platform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONM7p.png)

how can i associate an application to Parse, i can't create an account on this web site?

Comment: I think you just have an old link to documentation. They moved all of their documentation. Check the README of the github repo @Lyon linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Like what the previous person said, Parse.com has shutdown just a few months back. However, you can use the Open source parse server. https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example

More information is given at their github where they teach you how to deploy to AWS/heroku etc.